# Center of rect under UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar, center

I will probably sound stupid but i can't retrieve the center of the rect below the navigation bar.

I tried moving the center down by `[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] navigationController] navigationBar].frame.size.height` but seems that this returns a value of 0 points. I searched online but i couldn't find anything relevant.

How can i do?

Comment: Try `self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame` from your controller to get the nav bar frame. In your code shown your problem could be the root is the navigation controller, so try missing out the  `navigationController]` step.

Comment: tried it, also from the controller returns 0.0

Comment: i guess i'll have to hardcode the height to 44 points divided by two.

Comment: Where are you calling this code from and can you show it? Check each leaf of the hierarchy in the debugger by printing out self.navigationController  etc to check nothing is nil. Also make sure you call it in code which is after the view hierarchy layout has happened. e.g. In or after viewWillAppear and not in viewDidLoad.